# How to link base class only to its top-level templated parent?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Let's start with the code:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
class Link : public T
{
public:

    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr Link(Args&&... args) :
            T{*this, std::forward<Args>(args)...}
    {}

private:

    Link *next;
    Link *previous;
};

class Base;

using LinkBase = Link<Base>;
using LinkLinkBase = Link<LinkBase>;

class Base
{
public:

    Base(LinkLinkBase &parent, int a1, char a2, void *a3);

private:

    LinkLinkBase &parent_;
};

LinkLinkBase object {1, 'a' nullptr};
```

The code above does not work if I try to create an object of type `LinkLinkBase` - it fails because constructor of `Base` gets one parameter too many, because each template adds itself as the parent. So I'm wondering how to make this work, possibly without modifications to Base (I could move parent to be the last argument and ignore any excessive argument by variadic constructor)? I tried some solutions with `enable_if<>` or with multiple constructors in `Link<>`, but all my attempts failed and I have no more ideas.

What I'm trying to achieve is a *STATIC* list of lists, but without embedding everything into `Base`.

Comment: Why do you need to pass yourself (`*this`) to the parent constructor? You could just `static_cast` yourself to the appropriate child type, although this design seems weird at best.

Comment: I need this reference to avoid all downcasting. This way the code is 100% safe and without any "magic"...

Comment: You need to make a difference between the final `Link` and the intermediary `Link` because only the last one should send himself according to your design, so you might need a new class `FinalLink` wich passes `*this` while `Link` does not. Yet be careful, because you are passing yourself to your parent which is constructed before you, which could cause unwanted behaviour in some casses (e.g `virtual` functions etc.), that is not much less "magic" than a cast.

Comment: Is it possible to add such differentiation in Link, without adding another class? As for the "magic" you mentioned - it's relatively safe, I need this parent link only to obtain full type (with links for all levels, not just the "current" one and below that) for objects that are already on the list, so fully constructed. As I said - I want to create objects that can be linked in two levels ("vertical" and "horizontal"), but fully static, without dynamic allocation.

Comment: You could add another template parameter to `Link` and specialise on it for the two different cases(intermediary and final). Also it might be worth it to spend some time to see if a solution based on `std::tuple` or `boost::fusion` wouldn't fit your needs, it could save you some time and headaches by preventing you from reinventing an already existing tool with a lot of pre-existing support functions.

Answer (score 1):

Without touching Base, here's something that works...

```
#include <utility>
struct void_t {};

class Base;

template<typename T>
class Link;

using LinkBase = Link<Base>;
using LinkLinkBase = Link<LinkBase>;

template<typename T>
class Link : public T
{
public:

    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr Link(LinkLinkBase& derived, Args&&... args) :
            T{derived, std::forward<Args>(args)...}
    {}

    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr Link(const void_t&, Args&&... args) :
            T{*this, std::forward<Args>(args)...}
    {}
};


class Base
{
public:

    Base(LinkLinkBase &derived, int a1, char a2, void *a3);
};

LinkLinkBase object {void_t(), 1, 'a', nullptr};
// If you do not like the void, you can wrap this in a factory method
```

But with the pointers you are using, I don't think you will end up with a static list of lists...